# r pdf_text() split into lines and words

Tags: r

I can't upload the file into stackoverflow but I have a PDF containing a table spanning 3 pages. After using library(pdftools) and pdf_text(), it creates a 3 element character list where each element is a long string of all text from each page.

```
library(pdftools)
df <- pdf_text(file.pdf)
```

The data I need is on the 2nd page. I get the output:

```
df[2]
All Households                                                 19,015    10,030      8,985    3,635     585     3,055   19.1    5.8    34.0\n\nHousing above standards                                        12,365     8,225      4,145       0        0        0     0.0    0.0     0.0\n\nBelow one or more housing standards                             6,650     1,805      4,845    3,640     585     3,055   54.7   32.4    63.1\n\nBelow affordability standard12                                  4,885     1,230      3,660    3,125     535     2,590   64.0   43.5    70.8\n\nBelow adequacy standard13                                       1,360      555        810      425       75      350    31.2   13.5    43.2\n\n\n\n\n
```

I want to isolate the row "Below one or more housing standards" and the 8th column which contains the value "54.7".

I believe the next steps are to split the long string into lines by the line break character "\n", identify the applicable line, split the line into words, and select the 8th word.

I've tried splitting into lines using:

```
library(stringr)
lines <- df[2] %>% str_split("\n")
```

It returns a "List of 1" and I'm not sure how to work with it. Any suggestions on the syntax?

It's a bit convoluted to get to the original file.
https://www03.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/hmip-pimh/en/#Profile/126504/5/Alta%20Vista
Core Housing Need -> Full Report -> Export.
Oddly there isn't a way to just download a CSV.

Comment: Is this file available on the web? (It reads like documentation of a survey.) Your question is quite specific and needs to have the actual file to answer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readLines` (which doesn't use the `scan(text= ...)` pathway and therefore needs `textConnection`.

```
library(pdftools)
#Using poppler version 0.62.0
df <- pdf_text("Downloads/TableExport.pdf")
str(df)
# chr [1:3] "Core Housing Need (2016 Statistics Canada's Census) — Alta Vista\n                                           H "| __truncated__ ...
# for each page read in with readLines to make character vectors
# separated by \n
lines <- lapply(df, function(t) readLines( textConnection(t)) )
```

Then search for the line with the target:

```
lines[[2]][grep("Below one or more housing standards", lines[[2]])]
[1] "Below one or more housing standards                           6,650     1,805        4,845  3,640        585      3,055     54.7       32.4      63.1"
```

If you assigned that value to the name `target` you could get the 8th column with this rather baroque regex:

```
sub("(Below one or more housing standards)([ ]*\\d*[,]*\\d*){6}[ ]*(\\d*[.]*\\d*)(.*)", "\\3", target)
#[1] "54.7"
```

Notice the need to allow commas and decimal points in the numeric specifications. As written it may not be totally general since the first six of the numeric columns are only allowed to have commas and not decimals. I guess you could allow a character class like `"[.,]"` to be more general. Or even: `"([ ]*\\d*[,]*\\d+[.]*\\d*){6}"` (lightly tested). I suspect there are packages that will handle tabular pdf formatting in a more principled manner.

Comment: up voted for "baroque" :)

Answer (score 1):

This does not use pdftools, but I hope it is helpful to you. First, use `rvest` package to read the url of this table, then use html_table to extract into a table. Then, there is some manual manipulation

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url  = "https://www03.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/hmip-pimh/en/Profile/DetailsCoreHousingNeed?geographyId=126504&t=5"

# Read the url
doc = rvest::read_html(url)

# Extract the table, and provide anonymous V<x> names
table = rvest::html_table(doc)[[1]]
names(table) = paste0("V",1:ncol(table))

# drop first three rows
table <- table %>% filter(row_number()>2)

# Manually, identify the split rows (i.e. subheadings)
split_rows = c(1,9,24,32,36,40,44,48,55,62)

# Extract the subheadings
sub_table_names = table %>% filter(row_number() %in% split_rows) %>% pull(V1)

# Now, use lapply to filter the rows that are between the splits, and use as.numeric and str_remove_all to convert to numeric values
tables = lapply(seq_along(split_rows), function(x) {
  table %>%
    filter(between(row_number(), split_rows[x]+1, split_rows[x+1]-1 )) %>% 
    mutate(across(V2:V10, ~as.numeric(str_remove_all(.x,","))))
})

# Name the list of tables
names(tables) <- sub_table_names
```

Output:

```
$`Age of primary household maintainer3`
# A tibble: 7 x 10
  V1                   V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households    19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 15 to 24 years     1030    45   980   220     0   220  21.4   0    22.4
3 25 to 34 years     2700   715  1990   555    40   515  20.6   5.6  25.9
4 35 to 44 years     2795  1360  1440   545    25   520  19.5   1.8  36.1
5 45 to 54 years     3565  2005  1565   740   135   610  20.8   6.7  39  
6 55 to 64 years     3535  2225  1315   615   155   455  17.4   7    34.6
7 65 years and over  5380  3685  1700   960   220   735  17.8   6    43.2

$`Household Type4`
# A tibble: 14 x 10
   V1                                          V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
   <chr>                                    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 All Households                           19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
 2 Couple with children                      4360  3145  1220   585   100   485  13.4   3.2  39.8
 3 Couple without children                   4755  3195  1555   390    70   315   8.2   2.2  20.3
 4 Senior-led (65+) couple without children  2030  1695   335   140    50    90   6.9   2.9  26.9
 5 Lone-parent household                     2220   810  1405   845   135   710  38.1  16.7  50.5
 6 Female lone-parent household              1845   660  1190   730   105   625  39.6  15.9  52.5
 7 Male lone-parent household                 370   155   220   115    30    85  31.1  19.4  38.6
 8 Multiple-family household                  265   165   100    70    20    45  26.4  12.1  45  
 9 One-person household                      6075  2385  3685  1525   235  1290  25.1   9.9  35  
10 Female one-person households              3615  1590  2025   920   135   795  25.4   8.5  39.3
11 Senior (65+) female living alone          1810   980   830   525    90   435  29     9.2  52.4
12 Male one-person household                 2455   800  1660   605   105   500  24.6  13.1  30.1
13 Senior (65+) male living alone             600   350   250   170    50   120  28.3  14.3  48  
14 Other non-family household                1345   330  1015   230    25   205  17.1   7.6  20.2

$`Immigrant households5`
# A tibble: 7 x 10
  V1                                       V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                                 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households                        19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 Non-immigrant                         12500  7115  5395  1665   230  1440  13.3   3.2  26.7
3 Non-permanent resident6                 430    25   400   140    10   130  32.6  40    32.5
4 Immigrant                              6085  2890  3190  1825   345  1485  30    11.9  46.6
5 Landed before 2001                     4105  2480  1620  1065   275   790  25.9  11.1  48.8
6 Landed 2001 to 2010                    1340   340  1000   460    55   400  34.3  16.2  40  
7 Recent immigrants (landed 2011-2016)7   640    70   575   310    10   295  48.4  14.3  51.3

$`Households with seniors`
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  V1                                                 V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                                           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households                                  19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 Household has at least one senior (65 or older)  5910  4085  1825  1015   245   770  17.2   6    42.2
3 Other household type                            13105  5945  7155  2625   340  2285  20     5.7  31.9

$`Households with children under 18`
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  V1                                                         V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                                                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households                                          19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 Household has at least one child less than 18 years old  4465  2455  2005  1140   170   975  25.5   6.9  48.6
3 Other household type                                    14550  7575  6980  2500   420  2080  17.2   5.5  29.8

$`Activity limitations8`
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  V1                                                             V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                                                       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households                                              19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8    34
2 Household has at least one person with activity limitations 10955  5830  5120  2285   385  1895  20.9   6.6    37
3 All other households                                         8060  4195  3865  1360   200  1160  16.9   4.8    30

$`Aboriginal households9`
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  V1                           V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households            19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 Aboriginal households       655   215   440   120    20   105  18.3   9.3  23.9
3 Non-Aboriginal households 18355  9815  8540  3515   565  2955  19.2   5.8  34.6

$`Incomes, shelter costs10, and STIRs11`
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  V1                                             V2       V3      V4      V5      V6      V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                                       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Average household income before taxes ($) 96464   134172   54357   29101   31212   28696      NA    NA    NA
2 Average monthly shelter costs ($)          1256     1408    1085    1039    1243    1000      NA    NA    NA
3 Average STIR before taxes (%)                24       17.2    31.5    46.8    49.7    46.2    NA    NA    NA
4 Median household income before taxes ($)  72502   107762   44596   27711   28437   27568      NA    NA    NA
5 Median monthly shelter costs ($)           1097     1193    1076    1013    1115    1006      NA    NA    NA
6 Median STIR before taxes (%)                 19.3     14      26      43.8    45.8    43.3    NA    NA    NA

$`Housing standards`
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  V1                                     V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 All Households                      19015 10030  8985  3635   585  3055  19.1   5.8  34  
2 Housing above standards             12365  8225  4145     0     0     0   0     0     0  
3 Below one or more housing standards  6650  1805  4845  3640   585  3055  54.7  32.4  63.1
4 Below affordability standard12       4885  1230  3660  3125   535  2590  64    43.5  70.8
5 Below adequacy standard13            1360   555   810   425    75   350  31.2  13.5  43.2
6 Below suitability standard14         1480   210  1270   800    55   745  54.1  26.2  58.7
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check if there is more up to date 2018 data by following the crumbs to https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/46-25-0001/462500012021001-eng.htm ,

However, If you only want one row it is easy to save the source with right clicks,

```
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Below one or more housing standards</th>
            <td>6,650</td>
            <td>1,805</td>
            <td>4,845</td>
            <td>3,640</td>
            <td>585</td>
            <td>3,055</td>
            <td>54.7</td>
            <td>32.4</td>
            <td>63.1</td>

        </tr>
```

for the headings you need

```
HOUSEHOLDS TESTED FOR CORE HOUSING NEED 1   HOUSEHOLDS IN CORE HOUSING NEED 2   % OF HOUSEHOLDS IN CORE HOUSING NEED
    TOTAL   OWNERS  RENTERS TOTAL   OWNERS  RENTERS TOTAL   OWNERS  RENTERS
```

and for footins

```
1 Data include all non-farm, non-band, non-reserve private households reporting positive incomes and shelter cost-to-income ratios less than 100 per cent.

2 A household is in core housing need if its housing does not meet one or more standards for housing adequacy (repair), suitability (crowding), or affordability and if it would have to spend 30 per cent or more of its before-tax income to pay the median rent (including utilities) of appropriately sized alternative local market housing. Adequate housing does not require any major repairs, according to residents. Suitable housing has enough bedrooms for the size and make-up of resident households. Affordable housing costs less than 30 per cent of before-tax household income.
```

You have a PDF and want to work with the raw Text but its clear there is some issue with the generated searchable text and we can see that in the headings and with copy and paste. `Belowone ormore housing standards` so here is the expected extraction from bottom of page 2

```
pdftotext -f 2 -l 2 -nopgbrk -simple -margint 650 tableexport.pdf -
```

[image]